# Creating Objects with Different Environment Variables

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, environment-variables

```
class SomeThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        #to parallelizing
        os.environ['FOO'] = "http://localhost:1135" + str(self.name) + '/'

    def run(self):
        ...
```

I want that every time I create object with different 'name' (name is 'int' input), my object runs with different environment variable. I tried to call as follows:

```
some2 = Something(9)
some1 = Something(1)

#job2 = lambda: some2.run()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=some2.run(), name = 'job2')
t2.start()
#job1 = lambda: some1.run()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=some1.run(), name = 'job1')
t1.start()
```

But both thread are working with the environment variable of the some2 (the first created object's variable).

Comment: Environment variables are per-process, not per-thread.

Comment: What do you need an environment variable for?

Comment: If you need information associated with the thread and each thread is associated with a particular instance of `Something`, why don't you put the information you need as an attribute of the `Something`-instance?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, your comment solved my problem.

Comment: The library that use can not build individual connection with more than one slave which are sharing the same namespace. In order to send specific commands, I needed to run them with different env. variables. @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: @ascripter I have already tried this with Thread, but it could not change env. var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved, here is the code:

```
class SomeThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        #to parallelizing
        os.environ['FOO'] = "http://localhost:1135" + str(self.name) + '/'
```

and

```
some2 = Something(9)
some1 = Something(1)
t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=some2.run())
t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=some1.run())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```